# Why does ranges-v3 not move elements even the iterator is std::move_iterator?

Tags: c++, standards, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, range-v3

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <deque>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto src         = std::vector{"123"s, "456"s, "789"s};
    auto movable_rng = ranges::subrange(
                           std::make_move_iterator(src.begin()), 
                           std::make_move_iterator(src.end()));

    auto dst = ranges::to<std::deque<std::string>>(movable_rng);

    for (auto e : src)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto e : dst)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compiled with clang 10 with libc++ and the output is:

```
123
456
789
123
456
789
```

As I expected, the result should be:

```
""
""
""
123
456
789
```

**Why does ranges-v3 not move elements even the iterator is** `std::move_iterator`**?**

======= Update =======

My ranges version is : `range-v3-0.10.0`. Even I replace `std::string` with `std::vector<char>`, the problem is still reproducible on my linux docker, both gcc and clang produce the same result.

However, the same code is ok on [godbolt.org](http://godbold.org), but I am not sure the ranges' version of ranges on [godbold.org](http://godbold.org) is `3.0.10`.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the expected [result](https://godbolt.org/z/wxpZQd).

Comment: My compiler is clang 10 rather than gcc.

Comment: clang shows the same [thing](https://godbolt.org/z/c5aFpV).

Comment: There's no requirement that moved-from strings must be empty.

Comment: Since a moved-from element only needs to be in a "valid but unspecified state," you have no proof that moving didn't happen. You could perhaps write your own class that logs when it is moved to better illustrate what's happening.

Comment: My ranges' version is: 3.0.10, @cigien

Answer (score 6):

The example code on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) has this:

```
std::string str1;
std::string str2 { "alpha" };
...
str1 = std::move(str2);
std::cout << std::quoted(str1) << ' ' // "alpha"
          << std::quoted(str2) << '\n'; // "" or "alpha" (unspecified)
```

Probably due to small string optimizations, there's no requirement that the moved-from string is empty. It's allowed to be left unchanged after a move. The only requirement is that it's still in a valid state.

Answer (score 3):

Moving from an object leaves it in a valid, but not defined state. It's perfectly possible that, since your strings are all small, the characters are all stored inside the object and not on the heap (SSO). This makes it less efficient (slightly) to zero the moved-from string after "moving" from it.